# How many $12$ character passwords include at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one digit, and one special character?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a problem that I can't figure out. The problem is:

How long would it take to guess a $12$ character password containing upper case and lower case letters, digits and $12$ special characters. Assuming that $1$ billion passwords can be guessed every second and there are no repetition of characters.
(The password must contain at least 1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1 digit and 1 special character)

So far this is what I got (c = combination): $74$ Total Characters, at least $4$ of these are going to be in password therefore:
$$\binom{26}{1}\binom{26}{1}\binom{10}{1}\binom{12}{1} \times \binom{70}{1}\binom{69}{1}\binom{68}{1}\binom{67}{1}\binom{66}{1}\binom{65}{1}\binom{64}{1}\binom{63}{1}\binom{62}{1}$$
$$ = 1.91438 \ldots \times 10^{21}$$ 
combinations.

which = approx. $1910000000000$ seconds to guess the password.

Is this working correct? Assuming that order within the password is important.

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is not.  You are over counting.  You need to use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to count passwords that contain at least one uppercase, at least one lowercase, at least one digit, and at least one special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $26$ uppercase letters, $26$ lowercase letters, $10$ digits, and $12$ special characters, giving a total of $74$ characters.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition is 
$$P(74, 12) = \binom{74}{12}12!$$
From these, we must subtract those cases in which uppercase letters, lowercase letters, digits, or special characters are missing.

Let $U$, $L$, $D$, and $S$ denote, respectively, the set of $12$-character passwords from which uppercase letters are missing, lowercase letters are missing, digits are missing, and special characters are missing.

What we wish to find is 
$$P(74, 12) - |U \cup L \cup D \cup S|$$
By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),
\begin{align*}
|U \cup L \cup D \cup S| & = |U| + |L| + |D| + |S|\\
                         & \quad - |U \cap L| - |U \cap D| - |U \cap S| - |L \cap D| - |L \cap S| - |D \cap S|\\ 
                         & \qquad + |U \cap L \cap D| + |U \cap L \cap S| + |U \cap D \cap S| + |L \cap D \cap S|\\
                         & \quad \qquad - |U \cap L \cap D \cap S|
\end{align*}

$|U|$:  If uppercase letters are missing, then there are $74 - 26 = 48$ characters available.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $48$-characters is
$$P(48, 12)$$

$|L|$:  If lowercase letters are missing, then there are $74 - 26 = 48$ characters available.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $48$-characters is
$$P(48, 12)$$

$|D|$:  If digits are missing, then there are $74 - 10 = 64$ characters available.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $64$-characters is
$$P(64, 12)$$

$|S|$:  If special characters are missing, then there are $74 - 12 = 62$ characters available.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $62$-characters is
$$P(62, 12)$$

$|U \cap L|$:  If both uppercase and lowercase letters are missing, then there are $74 - 26 - 26 = 22$ characters available.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $22$-characters is
$$P(22, 12)$$

$|U \cap D|$:  If both uppercase letters and digits are missing, then there are $74 - 26 - 10 = 38$ characters available.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $38$-characters is
$$P(38, 12)$$

$|U \cap S|$:  If both uppercase letters and special characters are missing, then there are $74 - 26 - 12 = 36$ characters available.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $36$-characters is
$$P(36, 12)$$

$|L \cap D|$:  If both lowercase letters and digits are missing, then there are $74 - 26 - 10 = 38$ characters available.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $38$-characters is
$$P(38, 12)$$

$|L \cap S|$:  If both lowercase letters and special characters are missing, then there are $74 - 26 - 12 = 36$ characters available.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $36$-characters is
$$P(36, 12)$$

$|D \cap S|$:  If both digits and special characters are missing, then there are 
$74 - 10 - 12 = 52$ characters available.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $52$-characters is
$$P(52, 12)$$

$|U \cap L \cap D|$:  If uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and digits are missing, then only the $12$ special characters are left. The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $52$-characters is
$$P(12, 12)$$

$|U \cap L \cap S|$:  If uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and special characters are missing, then only the $10$ digits are left.  It is not possible to create a $12$-character password without repetition using fewer than $12$ characters, so the number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $10$-characters is
$$P(10, 12) = 0$$

$|U \cap D \cap S|$:  If uppercase letters, digits, and special characters are missing, then only the $26$ lowercase letters are left.  The number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $26$-characters is
$$P(26, 12)$$

$|U \cap L \cap D \cap S|$: If uppercase letters, lowercase letters, digits, and special characters are missing, then no characters are left, so it is not possible to form a password.  Hence, the number of $12$-character passwords that can be formed without repetition using these $0$-characters is 
$$P(0, 12) = 0$$

Thus, the number of passwords that violate at least one of the restrictions is
\begin{align*}
|U \cap L \cap D \cap S| & = P(52, 12) + P(52, 12) + P(64, 12) + P(62, 12)\\
                         & \quad - P(22, 12) - P(38, 12) - P(36, 12) - P(38, 12) - P(36, 12) - P(52, 12)\\
                         & \qquad + P(12, 12) + 0 + P(26, 12) + P(26, 12)\\
                         & \quad \qquad - 0
\end{align*}
Hence, the number of admissible passwords is 
\begin{align*}
P(74, 12) & - P(52, 12) - P(52, 12) - P(64, 12) - P(62, 12)\\
          & \quad + P(22, 12) + P(38, 12) + P(36, 12) + P(38, 12) + P(36, 12) + P(52, 12)\\
          & \qquad - P(12, 12) - P(26, 12) - P(26, 12)
\end{align*}

Comment: Correct me if wrong but the P(48, 12) means 48p12? like on the calculator

Comment: $P(n, k)$ means $\binom{n}{k}k! = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$.

Comment: Can you explain to me how the: 74c12 . 12! is equal to the total amount of combinations without repititon, is Multiplying the 74c12 by 12! the same as 74c12 x 73c12 x 72c12 ....... x 63c12 ?

Comment: By definition, $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$, so $\binom{n}{k}k! = \frac{n!}{(n - k)!}$.  Therefore, \begin{align*}P(74, 12) & = \frac{74}{12} \cdot 12!\\ & = \frac{74!}{12!62!}  \cdot 12!\\ & = \frac{74!}{62!}\\ & = \frac{74 \cdot 73 \cdot 72 \cdot 71 \cdot 70 \cdot 69 \cdot 68 \cdot 67 \cdot 66 \cdot 65 \cdot 64 \cdot 63 \cdot 62!}{62!}\\ & = 74 \cdot 73 \cdot 72 \cdot 71 \cdot 70 \cdot 69 \cdot 68 \cdot 67 \cdot 66 \cdot 65 \cdot 64 \cdot 63\end{align*} which is the number of ordered selections of $12$ distinct characters from the $74$ available characters.